# Secure way to use database values

Tags: flutter, realm, flutter-getx

I am using realm local database, saving sensitive values on it, i already encrypted it.
Is it fine to create an object from the realm database and keep it & use it the whole time when the app is running ?

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  RealmResults<Animals> animals;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    animals = realm.all<Animals>();
  }
}
```

(I dont understand securing secret keys and sensitive values in the code, that's why i am confused about all of that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume when state say *'i also encrypted it'* that actually means you're using an [Encrypted Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/flutter/realm-database/encrypt/)

If that's the case then yes, the data is secure in your local realm and you can use it as described in the question.

If you are using some other method for encryption, I would suggest using an Encrypted Realm instead.

> I dont understand securing secret keys and sensitive values in the
> code

That's because code can be decompiled and parsed - hard coded values could possibly be seen in the clear if that were to happen. Best Practice is to never hard-code passwords or sensitive data in an app.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, so anything inside the code is fine to do except typing something like :
String key = "abc123bla"; ?

Comment: @abdelrahman Correct. At a high level, data moving around inside an app while it's running is dynamic; when vars and functions (even the app itself) goes out of scope, that data is released e.g. it 'vanishes'. Whereas, hard coded data stays in the app, even when it's not running, so it's more easily accessed.

Comment: When you say "vars and functions (even the app itself) goes out of scope" is that include static too ? - what do you mean by "goes out of scope" ?

Comment: @abdelrahman Those are programming terms; In a nutshell, a variable defined within a function only exists within that function. When the function ends that memory is released and those variables go out of scope - search the internet for 'variable goes out of scope' for bunch of reading. Best Practice is to never put sensitive data in an apps code, regardless of how it's assigned (let, var, static etc)